# find total occurences of a list of words in a given column (SQL/Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a SQL database of information about the users of a certain platform.
The database has two columns: username, description

I also have a list of words/expressiosn (about 200 words in total) that I want to check if they exist in the description of each user:

**words = ['python', 'css', 'html', ...]**

what I want to do, is to create a new column - for instance named 'total'- and then count the total number of words/expressions in the list that are used in each user's description.

In other words, this is what I want using a nested for-loop:

```
for user in users:
    for word in words:
        if word in user.description:
            user.total += 1
```

However, the size of my data is quite big (5+ million users) and I want to know if there are more efficient ways to achieve this goal. I prefer to do it with SQL, however Python Pandas default functions would also be helpful.

The end result should look something like this:

| username | description | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| afhkjh | Python Nerd, Swimming | 1 |
| vnjfnn | Conservative, HTML Developer | 1 |
| af5a45 | NA | 0 |
| afkjah | Love working with CSS and HTML | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> words = ['python', 'css', 'html']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'username': {0: 'afhkjh', 1: 'vnjfnn', 2: 'af5a45', 3: 'afkjah'},
 'description': {0: 'Python Nerd, Swimming',
  1: 'Conservative, HTML Developer',
  2: 'NA',
  3: 'Love working with CSS and HTML'}})
>>> df

    username    description
0   afhkjh      Python Nerd, Swimming
1   vnjfnn      Conservative, HTML Developer
2   af5a45      NA
3   afkjah      Love working with CSS and HTML

>>> df['total'] = df.description.str.lower().apply(str.split).apply(lambda x:len(set(words) & set(x)))
>>> df

    username    description                     total
0   afhkjh      Python Nerd, Swimming           1
1   vnjfnn      Conservative, HTML Developer    1
2   af5a45      NA                              0
3   afkjah      Love working with CSS and HTML  2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perferctly for single words! However, in my list there are also many expressions that contain more than one word, like 'R Programming' or 'Object Oriented Programming' or things like that. How can such expressions also be counted? This is why I initially wanted to check like (if expression in description) so that regardless of the length of expression it can be checked.

Comment: @MahsaZ does something like: `df['total'] = df['description'].str.extractall('(?i)({})'.format('|'.join(words))).groupby(level=0).size()` get you close?

Comment: Unfortunately, this line of code found way more words/expressions that actually existed in the description, for all of the rows. The minimum amount of words found for a row was 17, and the maximum was around 70.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = []
for user in users:
    count.append(sum(word in user.description for word in words))
df["Total"] = Count
```

There could be better ways. The following block took 3.6s to run for me

```
words = ["quick","lazy"]
temp = []
for i in range(5000000):
    temp.append(sum(word in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" for word in words))
```

You can try to switch the other way round if `user.description` is shorter than list of words using `user.description.split(" ")`

Also, consider using `Set` if words are heavily repeated in `user.description`